# Trying to fit a sidewaysfigure below the title, but it keeps adding a page after the titel and figure is on next page

Tags: graphics

I'm trying to put a sidewaysfigure in the same page as the title of the section, but it keeps having blank space on the page with the title and then the image on the next page

```
\section{sectiontitle}
\begin{sidewaysfigure}[ht]
    \includegraphics[width=0.8\textwidth]{image}
    \caption{caption}
    \label{fig:PropProf}
\end{sidewaysfigure}
```

Comment: Would you be able to edit in a bit more code to your example, to produce something that compiles and has the problem? Figure placement can be finicky, and this will help people all have a consistent source to work with.

Comment: By design, `sidewaystable` and `sidewaysfigure` environment occupy an entire page -- no other material (except, I suppose, header and footer material such as the page number) allowed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.8\textheight` was too big.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{showframe}

\begin{document}
\section{sectiontitle}
\rotatebox{90}{\begin{minipage}{0.75\textheight}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}
    \captionof{figure}{caption}
    \label{fig:PropProf}
\end{minipage}}
\end{document}
```

[image: sidewways figure]